# Why iterators and generators are hashable?

Tags: python, hash, iterator, generator

As title. I mean, you can invoke `next(obj)` and point to the next element. So the internal state of the iterable or generator will change.

Why they are hashable?

Comment: they are hashed by identity, which is consistent with how their equality semantics work

Comment: The internal state may change, but the iterator *itself* does not.

Comment: @chepner: I do not catch the point...

Comment: Take `x = itertools.count(5)` for example. If you call `next(x)`, it will modify the internal state of `x` and return 5. The next time you call `next(x)`, though, you *know* it will return 6; there is nothing you can do to `x` itself to change that. In that sense, `x` is immutable.

Comment: `count(5)` is hashable because its hash doesn't depend on the current state of the iterator; whether `next(x)` returns 6 or 19 or whatever next doesn't change the fact that `count(5)` represents an infinite sequence of integers starting with 5. By contrast, an instance of `list` has no unique identity (and thus hash) beyond its current contents, because given any two lists `x` and `y`, you can make them equivalent via a series of `pop` and `append` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule for hashing objects is:

1. Unless `__eq__` is overridden, object equality is defined by identity, and hashing matches
2. If `__eq__` is overridden, and `__hash__` is not, then hashing is blocked by default (because mutability *that affects the result of an equality check* would break the hash invariants); re-enabling hashing requires implementing `__hash__`, which implicitly says "My equality and hash semantics are stable/consistent over time", but doesn't require that things not tied to equality or the hash code be stable.

Point is, the condition for hashability isn't *full* immutability, it's *consistency with equality* (and implied stability of both equality and hash). Since most iterators and all generators don't implement `__eq__` (there is no meaningful way to implement it without running out the iterator and losing the information you just used to compare it), it's all based on identity, just like with any user-defined object that doesn't define equality.

Comment: Ok, but in this way iterators, generators, any object that does not define `__eq__` and any object that is mutable but implements `__hash__` can be used as keys for a `dict`. Is this desiderable?

Comment: @MarcoSulla: There are use cases for it. Among the most basic is a sort of token-keyed data store; when a new store entry is needed, you just make an `object()` and use it as the key. Anyone with a reference to the object can retrieve the associated data. No one can accidentally share a key, and lookups are as cheap as can be. Similarly, whenever all objects of a type are considered unique, and you receive (potentially identical) objects from multiple sources, `set` will work for deduplicating by identity, which would otherwise be rather annoying.

Comment: `No one can accidentally share a key` I have not understood this point.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: If you need to make a new key in the store, guaranteed to not overlap anyone else's existing key, you can just do `mynewkey = object()`. Since `object()` (like all objects that don't override `__eq__` and `__hash__`) compares and hashes based on identity, the newly created `object()` *must* be different from all other objects that exist, and all other objects that could be created later (if all references to the object go away, a new object could be created that happens to reuse the memory, but the data store itself prevents the object going away), so the only way to have...

Comment: ...to the key is to have created it yourself, or to pass a reference to it to some other function/object/what-have-you to allow it to also use the key for looking up the same data.

Comment: Emh... a simple incrementing integer is not enough?

Comment: @MarcoSulla: Now you need to make a single global source of said integers. And protect it with a lock it in case two threads ask for a new key at the same time. And hope no one uses a random integer, or an integer from a different source, to look up data they shouldn't. `object()` has none of those problems; it's globally unique without any form of synchronization (aside from what's embedded in the memory manager itself), and duplicates *can't* be generated independently as long as the original exists.

Comment: And what about `uuid.uuid4()`? Maybe is slower, but more human readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201395/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-marco-sulla).

Answer (score 0):

While the internal state of the generator can change, the generator as a whole can never add something to itself, and can never go back a step while iterating over it. Therefore, a generator is a fixed immutable object, which is almost the definition of being hashable.

But even more deeply than that, even mutable objects can be hashable as long as they define `__hash__` as an instance method, but that is rarely desireable for mutable objects.

Comment: Specifically, a valid `__hash__` implementation will ignore the mutable parts of a mutable object.

Comment: So the fact that an object implements `__hash__` is a necessary but not sufficient condition for that object to be immutable?

Comment: @MarcoSulla no. the only condition for an object to be immutable is that it exposes no mutator methods. That's it. It need not define a `__hash__` method

Comment: @MarcoSulla More like the hash calculation, in order to be *valid* as a hash, cannot depend on mutable state.

Comment: @MarcoSulla no, any object (mutable or immutable) can implement `__hash__`, the definition of immutable is different, it is an object that can't be changed "in-place" and any change to it must replace it. iterating over a generator isn't changing the generator, it's just reading it piece by piece

Comment: @OferSadan: I don't think that's a useful argument. Clearly the generator is different after being iterated; trying to claim it's not changed at all is spurious on its face. The important part is that its state doesn't change in any way that affects equality comparisons; it remains equal to itself, and not equal to *everything* else.